# Conversion of tuples in pig

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I have my input as follows

```
sachin,rooney,rajni
```

And I want output as

```
sachin
rooney
rajni
```

I tried pig script as follows

```
A = load'input' using PigStorage(',');
B = foreach A generate FLATTEN(*);
```

But it gives the output as it is

```
sachin,rooney,rajni
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script

```
A = load 'input';

B = foreach a generate FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($0,','));

C = foreach B generate FLATTEN(TOBAG(*));
```